# Price Comparison in view formatting and highlight different price in different color

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am new to SharePoint. I have 4 different price columns ( different vendor price) for one item in a SharePoint list. I want to highlight the price in each field in a way that:

- 1st Highest price : Red
- 2nd highest price : Orange
- 3rd highest price : yellow
- Lowest price : Green

Each time when I am adding the new prices into the list for the same, this color should automatically change.

Can you please give the JSON code for this comparison and highlighting the color?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to compare across the 4 columns for each individual item you can use column formatting to do this.

- You'll need to use a slight variation for each column (formats below)
- For simplicity, I just set the class of the columns to the standard `ms-bgColor-red`, etc. classes for colors. You could adjust the expression to not build a class name but rather set a literal background-color/color instead.
- You could also switch the `ms-bgColor-` portion to `ms-fontColor-` to set the text instead of the background.
- Please note that I used generic column names (`Vendor1`, `Vendor2`, etc.) and you'll need to update (find and replace) these values with the **internal** names of your actual columns.

Here's what it looks like in practice:

[image]

---

**Format for Vendor 1**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField.displayValue",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "='ms-fontColor-white ms-bgColor-' + if(@currentField >= [$Vendor2] && @currentField >= [$Vendor3] && @currentField >= [$Vendor4], 'redDark', if(@currentField <= [$Vendor2] && @currentField <= [$Vendor3] && @currentField <= [$Vendor4], 'green', if((@currentField <= [$Vendor2] && @currentField >= [$Vendor3] && @currentField >= [$Vendor4]) || (@currentField <= [$Vendor3] && @currentField >= [$Vendor2] && @currentField >= [$Vendor4]) || (@currentField <= [$Vendor4] && @currentField >= [$Vendor2] && @currentField >= [$Vendor3]), 'orangeLight', 'yellow')))"
  }
}
```

---

**Format for Vendor 2**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField.displayValue",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "='ms-fontColor-white ms-bgColor-' + if(@currentField >= [$Vendor1] && @currentField >= [$Vendor3] && @currentField >= [$Vendor4], 'redDark', if(@currentField <= [$Vendor1] && @currentField <= [$Vendor3] && @currentField <= [$Vendor4], 'green', if((@currentField <= [$Vendor1] && @currentField >= [$Vendor3] && @currentField >= [$Vendor4]) || (@currentField <= [$Vendor3] && @currentField >= [$Vendor1] && @currentField >= [$Vendor4]) || (@currentField <= [$Vendor4] && @currentField >= [$Vendor1] && @currentField >= [$Vendor3]), 'orangeLight', 'yellow')))"
  }
}
```

---

**Format for Vendor 3**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField.displayValue",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "='ms-fontColor-white ms-bgColor-' + if(@currentField >= [$Vendor1] && @currentField >= [$Vendor2] && @currentField >= [$Vendor4], 'redDark', if(@currentField <= [$Vendor1] && @currentField <= [$Vendor2] && @currentField <= [$Vendor4], 'green', if((@currentField <= [$Vendor1] && @currentField >= [$Vendor2] && @currentField >= [$Vendor4]) || (@currentField <= [$Vendor2] && @currentField >= [$Vendor1] && @currentField >= [$Vendor4]) || (@currentField <= [$Vendor4] && @currentField >= [$Vendor1] && @currentField >= [$Vendor2]), 'orangeLight', 'yellow')))"
  }
}
```

---

**Format for Vendor 4**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField.displayValue",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "='ms-fontColor-white ms-bgColor-' + if(@currentField >= [$Vendor1] && @currentField >= [$Vendor3] && @currentField >= [$Vendor2], 'redDark', if(@currentField <= [$Vendor1] && @currentField <= [$Vendor3] && @currentField <= [$Vendor2], 'green', if((@currentField <= [$Vendor1] && @currentField >= [$Vendor3] && @currentField >= [$Vendor2]) || (@currentField <= [$Vendor3] && @currentField >= [$Vendor1] && @currentField >= [$Vendor2]) || (@currentField <= [$Vendor2] && @currentField >= [$Vendor1] && @currentField >= [$Vendor3]), 'orangeLight', 'yellow')))"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Its working well when I am creating a new list .But it was not working when I am using the same json code for existing list of 200 items. Its showing all columns in dark Red color. I have also replaced the columns name in json code with my existing list columns name. I have changed the column name of my share point list 2 weeks back. I am not sure whether the json code is checking still the old column name  or not. Any Solution for this ?

Comment: You must use the internal name of the column. Quickest way to get this is to go to List Settings and then click on the individual column. The name will be in the query string portion of the URL: `&field=INTERNALNAMEHERE`, verify this is the value you are using in your formats.